# MVC 3 OrderByDescending not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm followed the ASP.Net tutorial here, and it worked fine: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Now I'm trying it myself and it doesn't seem to work. I'm new to programming in general, so please talk to me like I'm 7. Thanks!

Controller:

```
    public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "Name desc" : "";

        var students = from s in db.ComputerMaintenanceModels
                       select s;
        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "Name desc":
                students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.Name);
                break;
        }
        return View(db.ComputerMaintenanceModels.ToList());
    }
```

View

```
@Html.ActionLink("Name", "Index", new { sortOrder=ViewBag.NameSortParm })
```

When I click on the Name column, it processes, but the Order doesn't change. Am I missing something? Is my code correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are generating a query and then ignoring it in your return statement. You should use something like:

```
return View(students);
```

Comment: Because I have categories and subcategories, it's actually sorting them instead of the item inside. But that's a new problem I can try to tackle. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

And you would want to handle the CASE ASC part of the case statement:

```
    switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "Name desc":
                    students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.Name);
                    break;
                case "Name asc":
                    students = students.OrderBy(s => s.Name);
                    break;
            }

return View(students.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return

```
return View(students.ToList());
```

Instead

```
return View(db.ComputerMaintenanceModels.ToList());
```

because studens is the variable where you are holding your query.
If you return db.ComputerMaintenanceModels.ToList() you will keep using the same query, with no order.